# PHP - Modify array while sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array of strings alphabetically and set each key to be the same as the value (because isset() is so much faster than in_array()). I can easily do this by making two passes over the array, but I was curious if it's possible to do it in only one pass.

I'd like to turn this:

```
array(
    0 => 'car',
    1 => 'apple',
    2 => 'dog',
    3 => 'box'
)
```

...into this:

```
array(
    'apple' => 'apple',
    'box' => 'box',
    'car' => 'car',
    'dog' => 'dog'
)
```

I've done some searches, but I can't seem to find anything about this (mostly I can only find stuff about maintaining the key-value relationship when sorting).

I'm aware this may be seen as an attempt at micro-optimization, but I'm asking more out of curiosity than desire to improve performance. I'm hoping I can learn some useful stuff by tackling this problem so that I have the knowledge in the future.

**Edit:** This is being used to alter an enum field in a mysql database. When new features are added to the system, new enum values are needed in certain columns. Instead of tracking down errors and manually adding the new values, I'd like to make the system self-correcting.

Basically, try to insert a row. If it fails with the truncation error that's thrown when an undefined enum value is added, then pull the enums for the column, check if the enum is present (it may be a different problem causing the error), if it isn't, and the value isn't NULL or empty string, add it.

I'd like to keep the enum values in alphabetical order for my own sanity, and I was setting the keys and values to be the same so I could do two things:

1. Do isset($values($new_value)) rather than in_array($value,$values). This is why I need the values in the keys.
2. Use implode to build the ALTER statement: `$query_text = "ALTER TABLE table CHANGE column column ENUM('".implode("','",$values)."')...;";`

I realize I could use `implode("','",array_keys($values))` instead in this situation, but I'm curious about how I would do what I originally asked because there may come a time in the future where I need to do something more complex to an array while simultaneously sorting it.

**TL;DR:** I'm not interested in whether I *should* alter this array while sorting it, but how I *would* alter an array while sorting it.

Comment: Are you positive you will not ever get 2 `apple`'s and therefore loose one apple in the shuffle

Comment: As array is passed to sort function __by reference__ you need to store it in a variable. So, you can't do it in one line. Minimum with two.

Comment: What's the point of mapping the key to an identical value? Why not just `array_flip` the array?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Doesn't make much sense in terms of an array. Maybe the question should be, what is this actually used for?

Comment: I added some clarification. Not sure if commenters get notified about edits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
<?php

$original = array(
    0 => 'car',
    1 => 'apple',
    2 => 'dog',
    3 => 'box'
);

$values = array_values($original);
sort($values);
$keys = array_combine($values, $values);

print_r($keys);
?>
```

and it print out

```
Array
(
    [apple] => apple
    [box] => box
    [car] => car
    [dog] => dog
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to remove duplicates, sort alphabetically, and enjoy the performance of `isset()`, then just call `array_flip($array)` and then `ksort($array)`.

Specificlaly, `array_flip()` will weed out any duplicates and set up `isset()`

Alternatively if you want to generate identical key-value pairs:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4TgPb))

```
$array = ['car', 'apple', 'dog', 'box'];
sort($array);
var_export(array_combine($array, $array));  // no need to call array_values()
```

Output:

```
array (
  'apple' => 'apple',
  'box' => 'box',
  'car' => 'car',
  'dog' => 'dog',
)
```

I'll just make a note to future researchers... Although `isset()` is faster than `in_array()`, the performance benefit is eliminated if you are going to greater trouble to reconfigure your array of data.